# SSIS - Getting a Substring from Filename and Inserting into Database Table

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, ssis

I have several files in a directory. The file name convention is **`yob + year + .txt`**

Here's an example of one file name: **"yob1920.txt"**.

The structure of the file(s) is as such: **`name,sex,number`** (notice there is not year field as the year is a part of the file name.

The structure of my staging table is: **tblNames(year, name, gender, number)**

My requirement:

- Get the date part of each filename (1920, 1921, etc.)
- insert it into a staging table with a column called Year

I've created a multiple file connection, a foreach container and inside of that container I have a dataflow task that iterates through the directory and inserts the data.

The problem is I don't fully understand (even after reading several sites) how variables work in relation to the container(s) and the data flow task that actually do the work.

Can I have some guidance on getting a substring from a file name and inserting it into a database table that has a column that doesn't exist in said file?

Comment: I'm not sure this tip will be useful to your circumstances, but just in case: the Advanced Editor's "FileNameColumnName" property on the "Component Properties" tab for a Flat File Source will add the file name into the data flow in a column name of your choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you can use **Foreach Loop Container** (Foreach File Enumerator) to loop the directory where you put the source file. Thus you store the file name to a variable with **Variable Mappings**:

[image]

Then create a **Flat File Connection** with an Expression of **Connection String** with value of the variable:

[image]

Then you can use "Derived Column" to add a new column with substring of the variable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Morgan! This is exactly what I needed.